# sailjs move custom logic into a separate node module

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am working with sailjs, and I am currently building in some simple bootstrap logic that checks for existing records and if necessary creates some default data. This is all working well.

What I am attempting to figure out (and maybe it is more of a node question), how can I move that logic into a separate node module?

The logic currently looks as follows;

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

    Role.count().exec(function (err, numRoles) {

    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }

    if (numRoles > 0) {
      return cb();
    }

    //create the default role records;
    var roles = [];

    roles.push({
        "cd": "admin",
        "name": "Admin",
        "description": "Admin user of the system"
    },
    {
        "cd": "normal",
        "name": "normal",
        "description": "Standard user of the system"
     });


    Role.create(roles).exec(function(err, records) {
        if(err) {
          return cb(err);
        }

        return cb();
    });
}
```

This is all working properly. But, what I want to do is move the logic for Roles into a separate javascript file entirely. Something like;

```
var roleBootstrap = require('roleBootstrap');

module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

 roleBootstrap.defaultRecords().exec(function(err) {
     if (err) { return cb(err);}
     return cb();
 } );

}
```

with RoleBootstrap looking something like

```
module.exports = {


defaultRecords: function() {

    Role.count().exec(function (err, numRoles) {

    if (err) {
      return err;
    }

    if (numRoles > 0) {
      return numRoles;
    }

    //create the default role records;
    var roles = [];

    roles.push({
        "cd": "admin",
        "name": "Admin",
        "description": "Admin user of the system"
    },
    {
        "cd": "normal",
        "name": "normal",
        "description": "Standard user of the system"
     });


    Role.create(roles).exec(function(err, records) {
        if(err) {
          return err;
        }

        return;
    });      
}
```

I keep getting the exception Details:Error: Cannot find module './services/RoleBootstrap.js' when attempting to do sails lift

Any insight/advice/etc would be greatly appreciated. Knowing how to do something like this will be helpful.

I did consider adding the defaultData method to the Role model itself.. but I still would like to know how to create something like the above.

Thanks,
Dean.

Comment: Where is your roleBootstrap located?

Comment: I was putting it in the /api folder, as well as trying the services folder. I added a few prefixes to play around with it, but always got the same exception

Comment: If you add it in the services folder, for example CustomService.js you can access it globally by CustomService.yourFn. (you dont need to require it). I think your file has to end in "Service" like i wrote. Else, you need to include the path when using require. (require('../services/somefile.js')

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try right now.

Comment: That worked. I added the path to walk the source tree (../domain/RoleBoot.js). That ended up being the issue.